# Using QGIS to find and calculate parts of polylines within polygon?

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, line, analysis

I've already got QGIS (2.18.2) to

- add an ArcGIS shapefile with polylines
- create a polygon which is a buffer region around a subset of the polylines in the ArcGIS file
- add a KML file with one polyline
- reprojected the KML file into the same projection as the ArcGIS layer.

What I'd like to do is:

- split the polyline from the KML file into two layers: one with the parts of the polyline that lie within the buffer polygon, and another with the parts that are outside the buffer polygon,
- so that I can get the total lengths of the polyline within the buffer polygon and outside.

I tried to use the QGIS Geoprocessing > Intersection tool:

- with the buffer polygon as Input layer and polyline as Intersect layer, I get a polygon virtual layer with a bunch of features that don't make sense, and
- with the polyline as Input layer and buffer polygon as Intersect layer, I get `1005 See log for more details` in the Log tab.

I'm concluding from this that the Intersect tool is meant for finding the intersection between polygons, not polylines and polygons.

I found [a similar question that involves the Process Modeler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71837/split-polylines-at-polygon-boundaries-in-qgis), but am new to QGIS and going through the Training Manual (in lesson 12 now — looks like [the Process Modeler is covered in lesson 17](http://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/training_manual/processing/modeler_twi.html#starting-with-the-graphical-modeler)), so the Process Modeler approach is beyond me as I ask this question.

If there's a straightforward way to do this with tools other than QGIS+GRASS, I'd be happy to hear about alternatives, too.

Looking ahead (in case there are alternatives which have trade-offs down the line), I'd like to be able to automate this analysis so that

- instead of manually comparing one KML file's polyline against one polygon to find the polyline lengths inside and outside,
- I'd like to compare a set of hundreds of KML files' polylines against a couple of regions to find the lengths inside and outside the regions.

Comment: I think I may have found what I needed: Vector > Geoprocessing > Clip. I'm working on verifying that it's doing what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I also got "1005 See log for more details"

Solved by defining a save file, rather than use a temporary file.